# Play 2.2.2 Heroku deploy httpclient;4.0.1 download failed

Tags: heroku, playframework

Play application update runs builds/runs fine locally however Pushing to Heroku (after migrating to [cedar-14](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration)) is failing with the following:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1!httpclient.jar
```

After browsing I have tried the following to resolve the issue without any luck:
Set sbt.version to 0.13.5

The issue seems to be in Heroku's own build process.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

DUMP:

```
remote:        [info]   [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.3!jline.jar (11ms)
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        [warn]   ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
remote:        [warn]   :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        [warn]   :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1!httpclient.jar
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1!httpclient.jar
```

Build.sbt

```
name := "jmpdb"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "com.thoughtworks.xstream" % "xstream" % "1.4.7",
  "org.apache.velocity" % "velocity" % "1.7",
  "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6",
  "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.12.0-beta",
  "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson" % "1.12.0-beta",
  "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client" % "1.12.0-beta",
  "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-drive" % "v2-rev30-1.12.0-beta",
  "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-oauth2" % "v2-rev25-1.12.0-beta",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20080701",
  "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.8",
  "com.ecwid" % "ecwid-mailchimp" % "1.3.0.7",
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0"
)

resolvers += "jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/"

resolvers += "google-api-services" at "http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo"

resolvers := Seq("typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo")

// Only needed in development
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M")

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Plugins.sbt

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")
```

Comment: This seems like a problem with how your resolvers are configured. Can you share the contents of your `build.sbt` and any `.sbt` files under `project/`?

Comment: Also, you might want to try reproducing locally by deleting your ivy2 and m2 local caches, and then running `sbt clean stage`.

Comment: @codefinger Have edited the question with sbt files. I will try and repoduce locally as you suggested.

Comment: I have used play clean-all which clears sbt cache (I believe). The app still runs fine locally.

Comment: @codefinger As per answer below was issue in Heroku sbt cache. You were looking in the right place though so thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting with Heroku technical support the issue was related to a corruption in the SBT cache on Heroku. The steps suggested below resolved the issue (in my case the purge_cache as I had already been running sbt_clean=true):

```
$ heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true
$ git push heroku master
```

If that still does not work, please try purging the ivy2 and m2 caches by running these commands:

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a peaceful-mountain-6737
$ git push heroku master
```

Hopefully, this will help someone else going in circles.